# How to define global variable in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm developing in an environment where the JS-engine doesn't have a global variable (e.g. `window`, `global`, `globalThis`, or `this`, etc.). Instead all the variables that are normally accessible through the global object, like `window.Math`, are accessible by just using `Math`.

So in order for Webpack to work I need to define my own implementation of the global variable. I tried googling around and couldn't find any answers for this use case. Webpack has a config for `output.globalObject`, but that that doesn't seem to work for this.

Webpack version: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed as follows:

First to the root of the project I added a file called `globals.js` with my desired global object

```js
module.exports = {
    Math: Math,
    String: String,
    ....
};
```

Then to the webpack config, I added the following plugin to replace the global module from core-js (I'm using core-js for polyfilling):

```js
const { NormalModuleReplacementPlugin } = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
....
module.exports = {
  ....
  plugins: [
    new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /node_modules[\\/]core-js[\\/]internals[\\/]global.js/,
        path.resolve(__dirname, "globals.js")
    ),
    ....
  ],
  ....
};
```

And now the global object is replaced with the one I defined in `globals.js`